# Edit the default Magento2 cookie message

Tags: magento2, blocks, cookie, cms-block

I would like to change the text and button value of the Mage2's default cookie policy popup.

See how it looks now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWWmp.jpg

I would like it to read some different text and have a different button text.

How would I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

**Try following:**

> Copy file to your frontend theme and update text as you want.

```
FROM: 
vendor/magento/module-cookie/view/frontend/templates/html/notices.phtml

TO: 
app/design/frontend/[VendorName]/[themename]/Magento_Cookie/templates/html/notices.phtml
```

Comment: how to do it by custom module can u please provide me the steps plz

Answer (score 1):

You can find text in below template location :

```
/app/code/Magento/Cookie/view/frontend/templates/html/notices.phtml
```

To change that you should copy notices.phtml file and save this in your theme folder and update as you want.

Answer (score 0):

for future coders:
you need to override the notices.phtml file in **your custom Module** or custom theme and to do that you need two steps:

1. in view/frontend/layout/default.xml
   you reference the cookie container and the notice block ,and through the method setTemplate, you specify your own new notices.phtml like this:

   ```
               <referenceBlock name="cookie_notices">
                   <action method="setTemplate">
                       <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">
        Vendor_CustomModule::folder name/notices.phtml
                       </argument>
                   </action>
               </referenceBlock>
    </referenceContainer>
   ```
2. now you can copy the notices.phmtl contents from the Magento Module "module-cookie/view/frontend/templates/html/notices.phtml" into your own overriden notices.phtml
   and change the text and button as you wish.

**P.S.** as your setting the template in default.xml the starting point is your templates folder, so if we take as an example the magento phtml file the folder name would be html.